# Shouldn't I be able to change my upvote after six minutes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes

Specifically on [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20825/xor-is-it-possible-to-get-a-b-c-from-a%E2%8A%95b-b%E2%8A%95c-a%E2%8A%95c) there is an answer that at first appeared to be correct, so I upvoted it.  But after a while I discovered an error. I want remove my upvote and give a downvote instead.

It seems that by the nature of this particular (puzzling) stack exchange, realizing a part of the puzzle at a later time would be common, no?

**Edit:** After more exploration, it turns out I was mistaken and that answer is good after all, but hypothetically, couldn't there exist cases where a late downvote should be acceptable?

Comment: If the post is later edited, you can change your vote. Also, on this site, votes don't necessarily reflect the accuracy of the answer. Sometimes we award votes for work put into thinking, even if the final answer is wrong.

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/up-down-voters-remorse

Comment: @d'alar'cop I was gonna link to that! (Btw. Why don't that have an accepted answer?)